# Add difference and percent change of every column in a data frame?

Tags: r, plyr, reshape

I would like to be able to add the difference and percent change to every column in a dataframe.

I'm able to get as far as melting the data and performing the calculations, but I can't figure out how to cast or reshape it back together. I also have a sneaking suspicion that this is easily accomplished with **plyr**, but the n-1 rows returned by `diff()` gives me problems.

Using an included dataset:

```
library(plyr)
library(quantmod)
head(longley)

     GNP.deflator     GNP Unemployed Armed.Forces Population Year Employed
1947         83.0 234.289      235.6        159.0    107.608 1947   60.323
1948         88.5 259.426      232.5        145.6    108.632 1948   61.122
1949         88.2 258.054      368.2        161.6    109.773 1949   60.171
1950         89.5 284.599      335.1        165.0    110.929 1950   61.187
1951         96.2 328.975      209.9        309.9    112.075 1951   63.221
1952         98.1 346.999      193.2        359.4    113.270 1952   63.639

longley.m <- melt(longley, id="Year")
longley.m <- ddply(longley.m, .(variable), transform, valdiff=diff(c(NA, value)), valdelt=Delt(value))

head(longley.m)

  Year     variable value valdiff Delt.1.arithmetic
1 1947 GNP.deflator  83.0      NA                NA
2 1948 GNP.deflator  88.5     5.5       0.066265060
3 1949 GNP.deflator  88.2    -0.3      -0.003389831
4 1950 GNP.deflator  89.5     1.3       0.014739229
5 1951 GNP.deflator  96.2     6.7       0.074860335
6 1952 GNP.deflator  98.1     1.9       0.019750520
```

(I don't know why Delt makes it's own column name, but I've given up on that)

Now, I can `cast(longley.m, Year ~ variable)` to get back to the original dataset, but I want to be able to have the difference and percent change for each variable in a different column without performing the calculation manually on each variable and then rbinding it back together. I'm pretty confident I've tried every variation of cast to no avail...

**Update:**
Joran solved the Delt column naming issue: coerce it with as.vector!

Comment: It does? My problem is more about performing the same operation on every column and putting it back into a dataframe. I don't see a solution for that in there.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the source of the difficulties. I see what I can do to unvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd likely approach this more like @joran.

But if you want to continue along the path you were on, you could use `reshape()` from base R to complete the journey:

```
# Your code
library(plyr)
library(quantmod)
library(reshape)
head(longley)
longley.m <- melt(longley, id="Year")

# My addition
longley.m <- ddply(longley.m, .(variable), transform, 
                   valdiff = diff(c(NA, value)), 
                   valdelt = as.vector(Delt(value)))
reshape(longley.m, idvar="Year", timevar="variable", direction="wide")
```

Comment: I think this gives me exactly what I was looking for. Reshape was not clicking for me. Thank you!

Comment: Heh. A lot of people have that experience with `reshape`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the strange column name when using `Delt` is that is returns a matrix, rather than a vector. Coercing it with `as.vector` solves that mystery.

However, I suspect that you are making this much too complicated. Is there a reason you can't simply sort the data frame by year, and then apply `diff` and `Delt` to each column, renames the columns appropriately, and then `cbind` them together?

Some starter code:

```
longley.o <- arrange(longley,Year)
apply(longley.o,2,function(x){c(NA,diff(x))})
apply(longley.o,2,Delt)
```

A more complete version (no hand entering of columns):

```
longley.o <- arrange(longley,Year)
valdiff <- apply(longley.o,2,function(x){c(NA,diff(x))})
valdelt <- apply(longley.o,2,Delt)

colnames(valdiff) <- paste("valdiff",colnames(valdiff),sep = ".")
colnames(valdelt) <- paste("valdelt",colnames(valdelt),sep = ".")

out <- cbind(longley.o,
             valdiff[,-match("Year",colnames(longley.o))],
             valdelt[,-match("Year",colnames(longley.o))])
```

Comment: Thank you for solving the first mystery! Although I do tend to over complicate things, in this case I have a feeling I'm on the right path at least. The problem with simply doing the diff and Delt on each column (before I melt it) is that I want it by each year for each variable. I would have to explicitly enter each column in your solution. My actual problem has 20+ columns in about a dozen different dataframes, so I'm looking for the easy way out.

Comment: @Totovader I don't really follow your reasoning. If you'd rather use reshape, then Josh has you covered. My update above should give the same results as his answer.

Comment: I see where you were going, now- the match part of your cbind part is foreign to me, so it would have been a few extra steps.

Comment: Be careful using apply on data frames - it will coerce to a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the strategy of melting and then processing within categories of an indicator was unnecessarily complex. If you wanted a dataframe with an added row of NA's at the begining so it would match up with the row numbers then two alternatives suggest themselves as one liners:

```
as.data.frame( lapply(longley, function(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
```

Or if you knew that all entries were numeric (as suggested by the use of a numeric function) and are therefore OK with using `apply` then this approach is even simpler:

```
apply(longley,2, FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
```

And if you wanted these all together with the Delt results:

```
cbind(apply(longley,2, FUN=function(x) c(NA, diff(x))), 
      apply(longley,2, Delt) )
```